# Windows 10 can't connect internet via Ethernet cable

Tags: windows, networking, router, ethernet, cable

Recently bought a Windows PC. It is able to connect Internet via Wifi but not from Cat5e cable.

This Ethernet cable was used by my Macbook before and it worked fine.

I use a NBN router.

When I run diagnostic, it gives me:

> Plug an Ethernet cable in to this computer.
>   An Ethernet cable looks like a telephone cable but with larger connectors on the ends. Plug this cable is to the opening on the back or side of the computer. Make sure the other end of the cable is plugged in to the router. If it does not help, try using a different cable.

Then I bought another brand new cable, and it still gives me the same crummy diagnostic.

```
ipconfig         

Windows IP Configuration                                                        

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:                                                      

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected                       
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway                                  

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:                                  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected                       
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :                                          

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:                                  

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :                                          
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c0b:3926:266d:208e%15              
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.99.1                             
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0                            
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :                                          

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:                                                    

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :                                          
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e199:4d55:471d:c430%16             
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.131.1                            
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0                            
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :                                          

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:                                                     

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway                                  
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:8003:4614:dc00:59b3:468c:5ef6:df68  
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2001:8003:4614:dc00:f54f:ce7c:b15a:aa18  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::59b3:468c:5ef6:df68%17             
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.19                                
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0                            
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::3291:8fff:fe44:93fe%17             
                                       10.0.0.138                               

Tunnel adapter isatap.gateway:                                                  

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected                       
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway                                  

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 3:                                        

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :                                          
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:18aa:1ea0:9a4f:b413     
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18aa:1ea0:9a4f:b413%14             
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :                                          

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D8804201-3778-40DE-9C8D-96E16DEA0457}:                   

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected                       
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :                                          

Tunnel adapter isatap.{DB15FA57-FCAE-4A60-8502-BE6E87480EBA}:                   

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected                       
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the ethernet driver instead? Sometimes reinstalling drivers may solve the problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your ethernet IPv4 properties are not set to a static IP address (unless you know exactly what network your router is on, and know about networking/subnets etc.).  I would recommend setting your IPv4 IP address properties to DHCP on your ethernet adapter.  It seems like your wifi is using the 10.0.0.x network so your ethernet adapter should pull a similar address from DHCP.

Comment: this makes a ton of sense from what the ipconfig output says.192.168.131.x is also a super wierd ip range.